# My Relative layout background not stretching full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hello in my app Relative layout background not stretching full screen.And it is displaying like below[image]

my xml file::

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CACACA"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Thats because scroll view. Scroll views child cant fill height.

Comment: Then may i know the alternative for this?

Comment: You may take the height of scrollview and the height of the rel. layout. if scrollview.height() > relativelayout.height() then relativelayout.height() = scrollview.height();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CACACA">


<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

......
```

Comment: Yup, but RelativeLayout's height should be set as wrap_content

Comment: @DoctororDrive yes, but it will not make any difference in screen output.

Comment: @PratikSharma i downvoted, because this doesn't stretch the view to the full screen as asked by KCRaju, also layout_height should be wrap_content and orientation shouldn't even be there. The answer provided by user2458464 is it.

Answer (score 9):

provide android:fillViewPort = true for scrollView.

Comment: this should be the correct answer, here for reference: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CACACA"
    android:fillViewPort="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```