# Android Studio App Dev. Relative Layout does not get background color in full device size

Tags: android, android-layout

Many similar questions were posted here, and I took my time to read them all. Majority of these posts uses ScrollView like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955100/my-relative-layout-background-not-stretching-full-screen/16955488):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CACACA"
    android:fillViewPort="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But i dont want to use scrollview. I only use Relative layout which has 2 childs, `lottiefile animation` and `textview` to display No Internet Error page. In Android Studio preview shows white background on device size as I expected, but when I test it on my Pocophone F1, relativelayout does not take any background color (even though white color is set). What am I missing here ? Can RelativeLayout fill the device screen background color at all ?
Here are screenshots and code I am working on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/noInternetAnimation"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/internet_error" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/noInternetAnimation"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/no_internet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check the screenshot, app preview on the right has white background as expected.
[image]

Now, check this when it is installed on my phone in real device.
[image]

Comment: Add your activity class code(if its fragment add both fragment & activity xml & class) & xml file name

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing your RelativeLayout to a ConstraintLayout just to see if it works? Your XML doesn't look complex at all, so I don't see why is not working